# To Disable the subviews of ABNewPersonViewController's view in iOS7?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, ios7

I want o make user interaction disable (not editable) for ABNewPersonViewController in iPhone by using the below code:

```
 ABNewPersonViewController *newPersonVC;
newPersonVC = [[ABNewPersonViewController alloc] init];
newPersonVC.displayedPerson = newPerson;
[newPersonVC setNewPersonViewDelegate:_addressBookDelegator];
[self disableTableCells:[newPersonVC view]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newPersonVC animated:YES];
```

The "disableTableCells" makes not editable to subviews of the "newPersonVC" view and I know the hierarchy is changed in iOS7,But I am not able to disable first,last name,photo and company name iOS7.
So the above code is working fine in iOS6 ,but not working in iOS7.

Comment: you're not supposed to modify the view hierarchy AND it might not even be a view in your process anymore. keyword: xpc

Comment: I am not modifying "ABNewPersonViewController" view hierarchy ,It's modified by Apple. It's Apple's hierarchy they modified it.

Comment: sure you are. you call disableTableCells

Comment: that doesn't work because view is nil I'd guess

Comment: - (void)disableTableCells:(UIView *)view{
    if([self isIOS7])
    {
        [self disableTableCellsForiOS7:view];
    }
    else{
        for (id object in view.subviews) {
            if ([object isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
                // visibleTableCells = [object visibleCells];
                for (id subObject in [object subviews]) {
                    [subObject setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: -(void)disableTableCellsForiOS7:(UIView *)view
{
    for (id object in view.subviews) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[UIView class]]) {
            for (id subObj in [object subviews]) {
                if ([subObj isKindOfClass:[UITableView class]]) {
                    for (id subObject in [subObj subviews]) {
                        [subObject setUserInteractionEnabled:NO];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Comment: So 1st for iOS6 and 2nd for iOS7.Now tell me who changed the  hierarchy and what is nil? I am getting view of the "ABNewPersonViewController" in both iOS6 and iOS7.

Comment: you are messing with views that dont belong to you. thats what i am saying. behavior is completely undefined and private.

Comment: Then how the messing with views is working fine in iOS6 and not in iOS7 ,only for first 3 rows of native contact first name,last name and company name ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening  only with pushViewController ::--

[self disableTableCells:[newPersonVC view]];
[[self navigationController] pushViewController:newPersonVC animated:YES];

So I replaced the above lines with the following lines and "ABNewPersonViewController" view disable problem with iOS7 is fixed::

```
UINavigationController *navigation = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:newPersonVC];
[self  presentViewController:navigation animated:YES completion:^{
    [self disableTableCells:[newPersonVC view]];
}];
```